# My girlfriend wants $1500 to prove she can look after herself when she arrives in Australia

Tags: money, australia, scams

My girlfriend wants $1500 to prove to customs that she had money to look after herself when she arrives in Australia. True or false. I'm questioning it. I do believe it's for real. She seems very genuine.

Comment: It's a scam. Run.

Comment: Have you lived with her or met her physically? If no then refer to the duplicate.

Comment: Australia has no such requirements.  This is almost certainly a scam.

Comment: Lies, lies, and goddamn lies! She's not your girlfriend, she's your user and scammer.

Comment: Send it to me and I'll pass it on to her :)

Comment: She's probably a forty year old fat bloke.

Comment: Why don't you ask her?

Answer (score 11):

Send her a deliberately vague sponsor letter stating that you will take care of her expenses. If she is genuine she will be pleased with it. If she isn’t she won’t accept anything but money.

We know the answer, we just want you to learn it before you are 1500 short. But Love doesn’t listen to random people on the internet, it only listens to experience. So try that and find out your answer.

Comment: @Jeremy Irwin As others have commented this looks very much like a scam, especially if you’ve not met in person up to now. If you do send her a sponsor letter you should only offer to cover accommodation, if you say you’ll cover expenses as well you’ll have to provide financial info to back it up and that could mean your bank account details falling into the wrong hands. Also, if you’ve not done so already, do your research - you should understand the visa requirements yourself, then you’ll know what’s mandatory and what’s not. And finally, don’t use your real name on an open website :-)